# Memory used by ImageView is never released

Tags: android, android-dialog

While building a Dialog which loads content view layout (setContentView)
I have noticed a weird thing:
The loaded layout has an ImageView with background of this Dialog:

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:src="@drawable/preloader_bg_small"
            android:id="@+id/background_img"
        />
```

Each time the dialog shows (in different activities) it drains memory (30mb) the image itself is 290k jpg loaded from local resource and NEVER gets released

I have tried to load the image programmatically:

```
((ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.background_img)).setImageResource(R.drawable.preloader_bg_small);
```

and then unloading it before the dismiss on the dialog

```
 ((ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.background_img)).setImageDrawable(null);
```

But then the memory gets released only after the activity is closed and not immediately.

Is there a way releasing the memory?
Why is ImageView behaves this way?

Thanks for help!

Comment: image drains memory 30 MB? you sure it's the image? what about trying DDMS memory management to see what causes the problem and what occupies that space.

Comment: When I remove the ImageView tag, It doesnt happen

Comment: I see in ddms that android.graphics.BitmapFactory allocates the memory.

Comment: Android and bitmaps are funny as they have a native object behind them which doesn't automatically get garbage collected. If you are dealing with the bitmap explicitly call `bitmap.recycle()` in your case I would try calling the garbage collector after setting the image drawable to null.

Comment: The problem is that I dont have the reference to the bitmap which is behind the ImageView. Probably I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although its still weird solved in following way:

loading image by setting drawable and not resource directly:

```
((ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.background_img)).setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.preloader_bg_small));
```

and releasing it from memory by setting drawable to null

```
ImageView background_image = ((ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.background_img));
            background_image.setImageDrawable(null);
```

Comment: @EB did you find a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Android manages `Dialog`s for you as an optimization. Unfortunately, it doesn't remove `Dialog`s after they have been used. It keeps them around hoping that you will use them again. In general, this isn't an advantage to your application. But that's the way it works.

What you need to do is to remove (delete) your `Dialog`s after they have been dismissed. You do this by calling `removeDialog()` when you don't need your `Dialog` any more.

Comment: @AmberBeriwal First of all, "deprecated" doesn't mean you can't use it, nor does it mean that it no longer works. If you read the documentation, it is deprecated because they want you to use `DialogFragment` instead. But if you are using normal old-fashioned `Dialog`, then you can still call `removeDialog()`.

Comment: I do not have much experience with Android development but I am facing the similar problem. I couldn't link the removeDialog() with ImageView. It would be helpful if you can provide some hint or sample for reference.

Comment: @AmberBeriwal Sorry, this is the wrong place to try to solve your problem. Please post a new question describing your problem. Asking a new question in a comment on some random answer isn't the wqay to get attention to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try `((ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.background_img)).setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);`
But it doesn't seem the image view problem. Your activity keeps link to image. Please give more code.

Answer (score 0):

An exemplary way to recycle a `BitmapDrawable` resource of an `ImageView` is using the following function :

```
protected void recycleDefaultImage() {
    Drawable imageDrawable = imageView.getDrawable();
    imageView.setImageDrawable(null); //this is necessary to prevent getting Canvas: can not draw recycled bitmap exception

    if (imageDrawable!=null && imageDrawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) imageDrawable);

        if (!bitmapDrawable.getBitmap().isRecycled()) {
            bitmapDrawable.getBitmap().recycle();
        }
    }
}
```